# Make Multiautocompletetextview scrollable above add button inside alertdialog and i want this type of custom alert dialog

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

Make `Multiautocompletetextview` scrollable above add button inside `alertdialog` and I want this type of custom alert dialog

[image]

Comment: What you have done till now can you update?

Comment: Please provide the code on what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even You Should Apply this method to LIMIT the Height of DropDown For `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` Widget in `xml` apply this change:

```
 android:dropDownHeight="size"
```

OR in through Coding:

```
autoCompletetxtView.setDropDownHeight(int);
```